# Trying to render iframe: ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'none'"

Tags: node.js, iframe, heroku, content-security-policy

I would like to render an iframe with the source being Github like so:

```
<iframe src="https://gist.github.com/user45445/9bf8d568e3350146ba302d7d67ad576f"> </iframe>
```

This is the error I get in the console:
`Refused to display 'https://gist.github.com/fresh5447/9bf8d568e3350146ba302d7d67ad576f' in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'none'".`

I was researching how to specify my `Content Security Policy` in my `Node` server, to specify that it should accept any iframes from `github`

So I installed [csp-helmet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/helmet-csp) and added this to my server code:

```
var csp = require('helmet-csp')

app.use(csp({
  // Specify directives as normal.
  directives: {
    frameAncestors: ['*.github.com'],  //I thought these two did the same, so I tried them both.
    childSrc: ['*.github.com']
  },

  // Set to true if you only want browsers to report errors, not block them.
  // You may also set this to a function(req, res) in order to decide dynamically
  // whether to use reportOnly mode, e.g., to allow for a dynamic kill switch.
  reportOnly: false,

  // Set to true if you want to blindly set all headers: Content-Security-Policy,
  // X-WebKit-CSP, and X-Content-Security-Policy.
  setAllHeaders: false,

  // Set to true if you want to disable CSP on Android where it can be buggy.
  disableAndroid: false,

  // Set to false if you want to completely disable any user-agent sniffing.
  // This may make the headers less compatible but it will be much faster.
  // This defaults to `true`.
  browserSniff: true
}))
```

But still the same error..

I have been trying to look at the [official docs](https://content-security-policy.com/) and the [HTML5 rocks guide](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/)

Not sure if I am super close or taking the completely wrong approach.

#### Update

I have also tried to set the CSP via `meta` tag.

```
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="child-src https://gist.github.com; frame-ancestors https://gist.github.com;">
```

#### than I received this error:

```
Content Security Policies delivered via a <meta> element may not contain the frame-ancestors directive.
```

Answer (score 23):

The `frame-ancestors` value acts on the *source* of the iframe not the document framing it. Setting CSP on your page will have no effect on the framing. Think of `frame-ancestors` like `X-Frame-Options` on steroids: it restricts what is allowed to frame the content. Gist intentionally does not allow directly framing gists but instead provides a way to embed a Gist.

`frame-ancestors 'none'` == `X-Frame-Options: DENY`

[image]

Comment: What if you own the content you are trying to embed, what does one have to do to be able to embed it? Are there server-related limitations in place that I do not see? I added the relevant URL to frame-ancestors but then I see Refused to frame 'https://my-url.com' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'none'". I do not have frame-ancestors set to none anywhere ...

Comment: @trainoasis that's interesting. One thing unique to frame-ancestors is that it goes alllllll the way up so if you frame content you own but that itself frames other content (protected by frame-ancestors) that won't be displayed. frame-ancestors is not applied by default so something is setting it somewhere in the chain.

Comment: @trainoasis I'm having the exact same problem you describe and this is on two websites I own inside my own network. I'm only setting the Content-Security-Policy on the page that will be loaded into an iframe. I've explicitly tried to set it to any with the '*' character but it didn't work. Same message you got and I haven't set frame-ancestors to none anywhere either.

Comment: @S.Mason I had to define frame-ancestors on the headers for the service that is running our UI and API as well. In our case it's Kubernetes ```virtual-service.yaml```, for Istio some examples here: https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/. If you dont set anything, the default is `frame-ancestors none;`

This makes sure that all our requests also include that

Answer (score 17):

As oreoshake points out, the problem here is not your CSP, but the CSP on GitHub. It is GitHub that is preventing you from framing them so there is nothing you can do with your CSP to resolve this.

Comment: So updates made to my CSP would affect how other sites wanted to use and engage with my app?

Comment: Yes, you may control how other sites are allowed to from you. This is what GitHub is doing to you.

Answer (score 0):

I got the exact same error when using the wrong URL in my iframe's `src` field. I had copied the URL directly from the address bar instead of clicking on `embed` and copying it from there.