# Unable to load an URL using iFrame because of Content Security Policy

Tags: html, iframe, content-security-policy

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<iframe src="URL">
<p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

I am using the above code to load the url inside iFrame and i am getting below error:
Refused to display 'URL' in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors https://inteliapp-stage.grymatter.com URL1 URL2 URL3 URL4 URL5 URL6 URL7 
http://18.233.166.250 https://18.233.166.250  cdn.jsdelivr.net".

For security reason, i am not able to mention the exact URLs. I want to know what should i add inside meta tag for content security Policy to resolve the problem? If we cant resolve the problem then how we can load the url inside html code.Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This source: [Source 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55566652/11700321) suggests you can add a policy. This source: [Source 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38535491/trying-to-render-iframe-ancestor-violates-the-following-content-security-policy) suggests it's not possible unless the site you're pulling the data from has an embed link to offer you. You could look into both!

Answer (score 0):

The page you're trying to put in the frame has the policy that's being violated.  There isn't any way to *weaken* CSP rules once sent; so unless you can modify the source of the framed page, there's not much you can do here.

You may be able to use an alternate method, such as doing an HTTP call in the background to fetch the content of that page, and manually insert that content into your page.